# MySQL select from specific ID until match condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this table:

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | condition | values |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 1  | a         | 1      |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 2  | a         | 2      |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 3  | a         | 3      |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 4  | a         | 4      |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 5  | b         | 5      |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 6  | b         | 6      |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

How can I get a new table that begins on `id=3` (including) and goes until `condition = b` (excluding):

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | condition | values |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 3  | a         | 3      |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 4  | a         | 4      |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

**added fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9882f7

Basically I want a table between a matching first condition (over a specific column - id) and a second one (over a different column - condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select t.*
from table t
where id >= 3 and id < (select min(t2.id) from table t2 where t2.condition = 'b');
```

EDIT:

This query works fine on the SQL Fiddle:

```
select t.*
from  t
where id >= 3 and id < (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.condition = 'b');
```

Comment: @kairos . . . I'm curious why you unaccepted this answer when it works.

Comment: I'm truly sorry about that! I clicked on the other answer by accident. Once again, this is the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop thinking of SQL data as having any order. Think of SQL data in sets; you have to search by *values*, not by positions.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM t
    WHERE id >= 3 AND `condition` = 'b'
) AS t2
WHERE t1.id >= 3 AND t1.id < t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, I believe this will work for you:

```
SELECT id, condition, values
FROM tableName
WHERE id > 2
AND condition != b
ORDER BY id
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: the problem is that condition could be also "c" or "d", I just want the results "from (one field - id)...to...(other field - condition)"